# Understanding execution of sequence of pipeline instructions

Tags: microprocessor, computer-architecture, mips, processor

I need help in understanding the solution from solution manual. The question is from the exercise 4.22.2 of chapter 4 in the book Computer Organization and Design by Patterson and Hannessey (4th edition). The question is about branching in instruction pipeline.

> **The question**
>     We assume that the following MIPS code is executed on a pipelined processor
>   with a 5-stage pipeline, full forwarding, and a predict-taken branch predictor.
>     Consider the instruction sequence:
>       `Label1: LW R2,0(R2)`
>       `BEQ R2,R0,Label ; Taken once, then not taken`
>       `OR R2,R2,R3`
>       `SW R2,0(R5)`
>     Draw the pipeline execution diagram for this code, assuming
>   there are delay slots and that branches execute in the EX stage.

The solution given is as follows:

> **The solution**
>   [image]

**Doubts**

- Why there is a stall (highlighted `***`) in cycle 7 for `LW` (4th executed instruction)? I understand that `LW` reads `R2` which is modified by `OR` ( executed in delay slot after `BEQ`, before `LW`). But `OR` reads it in cycle 6 in the `EX` stage. So `LW` should be able to execute `EX` stage in cycle 7 (since full forwarding is allowed). But why its not shown like that?
- Also notice that in cycle (column) 4, for `BEQ` instruction (2nd instruction), their is a stall (i.e. `***`). This is because `BEQ` reads `R2` which is loaded by `LW` (1 st instruction) in its `MEM` stage. So `BEQ` has to wait till `LW`'s `MEM` completes. However the same situation occurs in instructions 4 and 5. But in this case `BEQ` (5th instruction) is allowed to execute its `EX` stage in the same cycle as `LW`'s (3rd instruction's) `MEM` stage. Shouldn't `BEQ` (5th instruction) be stalled again to make it wait till `LW`'s (4th instruction's) `MEW` completes?
- Also I noticed, there are two 4th stages. In some instructions, 4th stage is labeled `MEM` (for example 1st instruction `LW`, 4th cycle) and in some instructions, its labeled `MEB` (for example 2nd instruction `LW`, 6th cycle). What are the differences between `MEM` and `MEB`? I searched whole book, but their is no mention of `MEB`, only in solution manual, its specified. Or may be I might have missed some pages.

Answer (score 1):

Your doubts seem well founded, there could be an error in the solution manual. Also the MEM and MEB could be typos, I don't have the H&P textbook anymore, but I don't remember learning about two different memory stages.

Do you have a professor to ask that assigned this problem?

Comment: I found that many (almost all) solutions have two states `MEM` and `MEB`, so I dont really think this can be a typo, giving how good this book is and how many times this has repeated in the solutions. The author must really meant something out of that, but he failed to detail it. However I do once found one typo in the other solution. And nope am not having professor to ask this. I am doing job and learning this independently for an engineering entrance exam.